# Lotus Notes - Java UI - Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes, lotus

Can a sidebar plugin use an actionlistener (or something else) to determine when the actionbar button 'save and send invitations' is pressed (within a new calendar entry for example)?

If so, can it also intercept the action and perform backend or ui modifications before allowing the button action to proceed?

Looking for any ideas on how to skin this cat (no actual cats will be harmed during coding).

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The code that runs when clicking actions on a Notes form, is not Eclipse Java code and doesn't support Java listeners. To do this sort of thing, you would have to modify the design of the form (or the shared action, if the action is shared).

Please also note that there are other ways to save or send a document, other than by pressing an action button. For instance, you can use Ctrl+S to save, or press Esc to be prompted whether to save and/or send. To intercept every occasion of a send or save attempt, you have to use the Querysave and/or Querysend events of the form (or of a subform, if there are any). Depending on the design of the application you're working on, there may be a subform specifically intended to allow customizations without editing the main form.