# How to hook the 'send' button in lotus notes client

Tags: lotus-notes

Due to some reasons, I'm not allowed to touch Domino server but would like to make my plugin be able to modify email content right before it's being sent in client side. All comes up in my mind is to add a listener or somehow to hook the 'send' button of a message, which holds on when being clicked and runs my codes, and then sends the message. Is there anyone knowing about this trick, or any other way to meet the same purpose? Thanks. 
BTW: I'm using Lotus Toolkit in Java.

Update:
I found a very similar question here:[Lotus Notes - Java UI - Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131848/lotus-notes-java-ui-eclipse-plugin)
But I found Querysend only exists in NotesUIDocument of LotusScript but not Java. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: install a DLL built using the Notes C API on every Notes client computer, or make  modifications to the mail template. In the latter case, though, rather than implementing your code in the QuerySend event it probably makes more sense to implement to implement your code directly in the click event of the shared Send action - and that is just Lotus' formula language, so neither LotusScript nor Java is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid programming in C/C++. For your latter suggestion, where should I put the modified shared Send action? If the modification is directly to the mail template, how to publish my codes so that my clients can update their Send action with my 'injection' as well? Thanks.

Comment: By default, there is a task that runs on Domino servers every night that checks templates for updates and pushes them into applicaitons based on the template. So once you replicate your changes to the server, it's all automatic. (It can be run manually if you don't want to wait overnight.) But note: you will absolutely need permission from your system admins to make modifications to the mail template, because doing that complicates server upgrades. Done right, this can be managed without too many problems, but in my experience it's not easy to convince admins to do it.

Comment: Yes it's better not touch server stuff and implement my hook without permission of admins of Domino server. But what you meant seems that if I modify the mail template, I have to deal with server stuff. Is there any other solution without dealing with server and C programming? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to create an agent or task to capture and intercept 'email send'? Could you explain how Notes C API works in my case? Thanks.

Comment: I beliefe I alread explained in the answer to your other question that the C API's Extension Manager can hook an event that is triggered when email is submitted. As for an agent, no, an agent cannot do that. The other thing that might be able to do it is the Lotus Expeditor Toolkit for creating Eclipse plugins that interact with the Notes client, but I have never really paid much attention to that toolkit or its capabilities so I don't know. I don't know if it gets events from the native Notes features, or only from Notes client framework features that IBM built with Eclipse.